# How to make json to json object in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, json.net

I have a json wants to add square brackets on it (means wants to convert it to json object array) here is my json in response,

```
    {
  "exampleJson": {
    "test": [
      {
        "xf": "G",
        "sas": "24",
        "ras": 5,
        "asd": 4000,
        "rer": 200,
        "asda": 0
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

Now i want this json to as below (Just square brackets before and to the end of the json)

```
    [{
  "exampleJson": {
    "test": [
      {
        "xf": "G",
        "sas": "24",
        "ras": 5,
        "asd": 4000,
        "rer": 200,
        "asda": 0
      },
    ],
  }
}]
```

Apart from concatenation is there any way to achieve this ? And this is a `JObject` which i have created.

Comment: Which library are you using for serialising/deserialising the JSON?

Comment: I am not actually! Using jObject.Add((new JProperty("exampleJson",value))); assigning the value to the jObject.

Comment: Then do `var returnedArray = new JArray(jObject);`.

Comment: Right, so you're apparently using Newtonsoft's JSON.Net library to handle the serialisation then.

Comment: Yep!! it works!! Thank you @dbc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surrounding `[]` indicates an array is being returned rather than an object, so you need to make your outer container be a [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm):

```
var returnedArray = new JArray(jObject);
```